How do I run Socket.io with next js in the same docker container with ssl on the domain
Cannot figure out how to run Socket.io simultaneously with the nextjs server on vps using docker. Did anyone face the same issue? I was thinking maybe running a separate server for socket io, but how do I get all together? Another question, do i need to use nginx or apache, any help is appreciated.
I deployed nextjs with docker on a vps, but then just got stuck trying to figure out how to connect the sockets.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
